# data-bind with multiple attributes and null check?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I m binding data using this code:

```
<a class="btnAttach" href="#" data-bind="attr:{'data-mmid':mm_id}" >
```

My data object is:

```js
{
  "mm_id": 1
  account: {
    "accId": "Acc1"
    "accName": "Az Corp"
  }
}
```

I need to modify binding. Currently code binds `mm_id` as an "data-mmid" attribute. But I need to add another attribute `accId` as separate data-accId attribute. Probably i can't have 2 `data-bind`. Please can you guide how to do this ? Another catch is `account` object can be null too. So further complaxity is how to do null check and create 2 attributes.

I highly appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-bind="if: account">
  account: <a data-bind="attr:{'data-mmid':mm_id,'data-accId':account.accId}"> </a> </div>
```

please check the above code.